# pass a variable as a DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZ

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to be able to allow my users to specify the Font size (and family) for a document they are creating.  I've got a Listbox of various sizes they select on a configuration page but I'm not certain how to assign it to the code.  For example this works fine:

'var lHeading2style = {};
  lHeading2style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]=DocumentApp.FontFamily.headingStyle2font;
   lHeading2style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
   lHeading2style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;'

However, if I set a variable as shown below, how to I attached it to my codeline?

var **headingStyle3FontSize** = '8';

var lHeading3style = {};
lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]=DocumentApp.FontFamily+headingStyle3font;
   lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = '**headingStyle3FontSize**';
   lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
// Formatting Styles

I've also tried 
   lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = **headingStyle3FontSize**;

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

You should use a number value for the variable, instead of a string value.

```
var headingStyle3FontSize = 8;
lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = headingStyle3FontSize;
```

Comment: Ahh.. thank you !!

What would be the solution for making 'headingStyle3font' a variable?  I'd like to allow them to select it from a picklist.

var lHeading3style = {}; lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]=DocumentApp.FontFamily+**headingStyle3font**; lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 'headingStyle3FontSize'; 
lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false; // Formatting Styles

Comment: The FONT_FAMILY attribute holds an enum value from here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_documentapp_fontfamily. You can't append a string to create these enum values, you'll need to convert your string value into an enum value. One way to do that is to have a switch block: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: OK, so the idea is writing all of this in my code

`var lHeading3style = {}; lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]=DocumentApp.FontFamily+**headin‌​gStyle3font**; lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 'headingStyle3FontSize';`

and then just testing the value from my picklist using 
`switch(font)
{
font='ARIAL'
 var lHeading3style = {}; lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]=DocumentApp.FontFamily+ARIAL;
lHeading3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 'headingStyle3FontSize';` 
break;

Comment: This isn't allowed: "DocumentApp.FontFamily+ARIAL". You need to use: "DocumentApp.FontFamily.ARIAL".